# List of dicts, drop if value of type 'list' is subset of another item

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, like so:

```
data =  [{'active': 'false', 'id': [u'PB1001216', u'PB1007555'], 'game': u'Game1', 'name': u'Test'}, 
         {'active': 'false', 'id': [u'PB1001216', u'PB1007555', u'PB1000395'], 'game': u'Game1', 'name': u'Test'}, 
         {'active': 'false', 'id': [u'PB1007555'], 'game': u'Game2', 'name': u'Test'}]
```

I want to drop the dictionaries in the list where the value of `game`, `name` exists and the `id` list is a subset of another dictionary item. The list with the most elements should be kept as its the most recent.

So in my example above. I would expect:

1. dropped because id is a subset of record below
2. kept as has the more elements that the subset in item 1.
3. kept as the game value is different

Any suggestions on the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Can this be restated as "group by the value of `game`, and keep only the item with the "largest" `id` list of each group"? Well, grouping is trivial using dictionaries (`groups[item['game']] = item`), and if you do that in a loop the other condition is almost self explanatory.

Comment: I suppose you could group by `game` and `name` first, but a list with fewer elements must be a subset of the larger list.

Comment: So what if it's not a subset? You keep both?

Comment: yes, keep both.

Comment: Loop, if `groups[i['game']][i['name']]` is set, another nested loop to check subset condition, then append to group list or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could iterate through elements popping the ones meeting your conditions:

```
data =  [{'active': 'false', 'id': [u'PB1001216', u'PB1007555'], 'game': u'Game1', 'name': u'Test'}, 
         {'active': 'false', 'id': [u'PB1001216', u'PB1007555', u'PB1000395'], 'game': u'Game1', 'name': u'Test'},
         {'active': 'false', 'id': [u'PB1001316', u'PB1007555', u'PB1000395'], 'game': u'Game1', 'name': u'Test'},
         {'active': 'false', 'id': [u'PB1007555'], 'game': u'Game2', 'name': u'Test'}]

for item in data:
    for element in data:
        if element != item and element['game'] == item['game']:
            if len(item['id']) > len(element['id']):
                if element['id'] == item['id'][:len(element['id'])]:
                    data.pop(data.index(element))
            else:
                if item['id'] == element['id'][:len(item['id'])]:
                    data.pop(data.index(item))
```

Comment: unfortunately this just throws an error: `{'active': 'false', 'id': [u'PB1007555'] ... is not in list` at this point here `data.pop(data.index(item))`

Comment: i tested the code above but it doesnt pop the first dict in the list, which it should do. thanks for the answer though

Comment: what version of pythonare you using?

Comment: try 'data.remove(element)' instead of 'data.pop(data.index(item))'

Comment: i used enumerate and used the index value to pop. this worked for me. also the slice is in the wrong place. but thanks for giving this code very helpful